# How to set ring volume to minimum?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

Following code set phone to vibrate state, I want silent mode without vibration.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an additional AudioManager method to silence the vibration. Add this after your original code:

```
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Full list of ringer modes can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode(int)

Comment: How is this not an answer to the question? It should achieve exactly what the OP has asked: "I want silent mode without vibration"

Comment: A 'one/two' lines of code without explaination fits in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I have added additional explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks :) sry for late response, I had been busy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
switch (position) {
     case 0:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
           break;
     case 1:
         audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
           break;
    case 2:
         audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
          audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, 
             AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
           break;
     case 3:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, 
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
        break;
     }
```

`setVibrateSetting` works fine when I use my nexus s with Gingerbread and IceCreamSandwich, I develop it with ICS, however recently I found it doesn't work with Jelly Bean, and `getVibrateSetting` also doesn't work. Waiting for a better way